# Цвет консоли c++

Tags: c++, winapi, консоль

```
system("color F0");
```

Меняю цвет консоли этой строчкой, вопрос вот в чем. Как после конкретных манипуляций восстановить дефолтный цвет консоли?

Answer (score 1):

`system("color F0");` - считается не корректным использованием `system();`

> Please don't tell people to use system(). If you are going to do
>   something OS-dependant, do it the right way.

[Первоисточник](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/5830/)
И приведенный код  **right way**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const WORD colors[] =
        {
        0x1A, 0x2B, 0x3C, 0x4D, 0x5E, 0x6F,
        0xA1, 0xB2, 0xC3, 0xD4, 0xE5, 0xF6
        };

    HANDLE hstdin  = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE  );
    HANDLE hstdout = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    WORD   index   = 0;

    // Remember how things were when we started
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hstdout, &csbi );

    // Tell the user how to stop
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, 0xEC );
    std::cout << "Press any key to quit.\n";

    // Draw pretty colors until the user presses any key
    while (WaitForSingleObject( hstdin, 100 ) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, colors[ index ] );
        std::cout << "\t\t\t\t Hello World \t\t\t\t" << std::endl;
        if (++index > sizeof(colors)/sizeof(colors[0]))
            index = 0;
    }
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer( hstdin );

    // Keep users happy
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( hstdout, csbi.wAttributes );
    return 0;
}
```

[Похожий вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559077/how-to-get-background-color-back-to-previous-color-after-use-of-std-handle)

*Если очень нужно*... установить `default` значениe, то `setColor(8 , 15);`
*Надеюсь помог!*

Comment: Встречный вопрос. Что делать если изменить нужно фон всей консоли а не только под текстом?

Comment: `setColor(0, 15);` - `0` - черный фон, `15` - белые буквы.